# Why does my service always bind to ipv6 localhost instead of ipv4?

Tags: android, sockets, localhost, iptables, portforwarding

I have a service that creates a ServerSocket and binds to `localhost:7060`. When I did "netstat -an" on my android device, I see it is using ipV6 localhost instead of ipv4 localhost interface.

The output is like this:
**tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:7060  :::*                   LISTEN**

The ports that use ipV4 are listed like this:
**tcp       0      0 127.0.0.1:5060           0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN**

What is the trick to force it to use IPv4 always?
I am setting up a port forward rule using iptables. The version I have supports ipv4 destination addresses.

This is how I am creating my Java code for listening on the port.

`InetAddress localAddress = Inet4Address.getByName("localhost");
    //InetAddress localAddress = Inet4Address.getLocalHost();
    sockServer = new ServerSocket(nPort, 20, localAddress);`

I followed other advice like setting system property to prefer ipV4 in the startup of my service. That didn't make any difference.

`System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");`

I am running this on Android 2.3 built for an embedded device.

Update:
I checked InetAddress.java sources in android tree. It is reading the above flag with a line like below.

```
static boolean preferIPv6Addresses() {
        String propertyName = "java.net.preferIPv6Addresses";
        String propertyValue = AccessController.doPrivileged(new PriviAction<String>(propertyName));
        return Boolean.parseBoolean(propertyValue);
    }
```

Now I am not sure System.setProperty() call is really changing the value read by above code.

Comment: I think those system properties are in the OS itself, and changing them programatically will not stick (because all apps depend on the same system properties).

Comment: (Since this older thread was referenced elsewhere, I think some clarification is needed.)   `::1` is the IPv6 localhost address. `::ffff:127.0.0.1` is not, it is the IPv4 localhost address in IPv6 notation (a so-called "IPv4-mapped" IPv6 address). It is used for dual-stacked sockets that can accept both IPv4 and IPv6 packets. (Although a socket should be labeled `tcp46`, then.)

Answer (score 2):

In theory a IPv6 server listens to IPv4 as well, since IPv4 address space is a subset of IPv6, is this causing real problems to you?

A trick that might work is to use "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost", which has IPv4 and IPv6 addresses associated.

Comment: using `server = ServerSocket(8080, 8, InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"))` on the device i tried with Android 11 still produces an IPv6 server as shown by `netstat -lte` (and not a `tcp46` connection as seen in other answers).